# Computer is running slow

Tags: windows

My computer has been performing well in everything. Well, I use it mainly for gaming. But now, when I was playing a game, the computer suddenly started running slow, and eventually fails to even boot up (actually it boots up in 10-15 minutes, but it is slower that I cannot even open This PC in the next 20 or 30 minutes). So, I bought a new HDD and reinstalled Windows 10 in it.

Luckily, the system started running as expected until I started installing more software, and now, it performs worse. I don't know which hardware is failing here. Everything from, window animation to games are slower, but it boots faster.

Installed the newest nvidia and Intel graphic drivers and Windows-recommended drivers for USB 3.0 since I have external hard drives too where games are installed.

System config:

- Intel i7 4790 @3.6 GHz, Nvidia GeForce GTX 960
- Gigabyte Z97M-D3H motherboard, Kingston HyperX Fury 8 GB RAM
- Corsair VS 550 PSU
- Toshiba internal hard drive (1TB, only around 50GB used)
- 2 Toshiba external hard drives (1TB and 2 TB, around 1.5 TB used)

Comment: The system performed well when you did a fresh install, so not likely hardware. Look for older or non-compliant software and/or third party antivirus that is not compliant.

Comment: Actually, I tried installing Windows on my existing hard drive (it's 10-year older). Since it has an MBR partition, Windows refused to install. And, I was not able to boot as non-UEFI. So, I bought a newer internal hard drive.

Comment: Currently running Windows 10 v1903

Comment: V1903 runs well on my own computers and all my client computers as well. Machines are generally less than 5 years old

Comment: @john Currently, only native Windows apps and hardware drivers are run on the system (in the primary HDD). I'm using Defender as anti-virus.

Comment: Windows only supports MBR if Legacy Mode is enabled.  If the UEFI mode is turned on, then Windows cannot be installed, on a MBR partition.  All supported versions of Windows support MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 needs a lot of ressources and it is heavily advised to run the CPU with a SDD instead with a usual harddisk.

I have a AMD Ryzen5, and replaced myself with an NVMe SSD and it solved my problems in life time.

The point is, that a usual harddisk with the amount of data Windows 10 demands is always under heavy load and it simply takes a long time until everything is loaded.

Taking a fast SSD you make also use of the FSB.
I would advise to take something solid fast for all times.

I bought a Samsung 970 EVO Plus (2TB)
and in your case you can get a M.2 PCIe, for example Delock:
https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_89370/faq.html

Also a good advise would be 2 make 2 accounts.

One for installations (admin) and the user one for daily tasks (user) that no viruses or applications are system wide installed.

If you have a virus or Trojan, it won't be capable to write in the systems registry when you perform your daily tasks.

Wish you all the best.

Comment: But, the system was performing better even with a 10-year old HDD, until 2 weeks earlier when it started slowing down.

Comment: Windows 10 is taking so much ressources, it is unbelievable.
Many companies were upset that no updates for Windows 7 are available, because the whole press informed that Windows 10 is a resource killer.

I advise to get a propper SSD or switch to Windows 7 where the support ends at 14th of january 2020. Sorry to say this, with the latest windows operating systems usual Harddisks don't have a future.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 properly setup will work fine on a 7200-rpm hard drive - I have an Insider machine this way.

If (you said) the system ran well, then slowed down, and remained slow with a reinstall and only native apps, then check the hard drive for errors (even if new) and for sure test memory with memtest86.exe.

If your vendor has a hardware test suite, use that to test the hardware. Also run the Windows 10 Upgrade Adviser (Microsoft Downloads) to check for compatibility issues

Comment: Sure, will do that. I have a 7200rpm HDD now

Comment: I had a 7200rpm harddisk as well, after a half year it said goodbye. Take it to a propper SSD if you don't like to have this problem again in a while.